# on pressing back button on device my app should close without going to any previous screens in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am wondering if anyone knows how to use the device back button to exit the app without going back to any previous pages/routes.

```
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: Text("NO"),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()),
              );
            },
            child: Text("YES"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ) ??
    false;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically exit flutter apps, you need to pop the systemNavigator like follow :

```
SystemNavigator.pop()
```

SystemNavigator is available after importing Services :

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

An other method is to use `exit(0)` which would terminate the app but is usually not user Interface friendly especially on iOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit your app using following ways:

1. `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop', animated)`
2. `exit(0)`
3. `SystemNavigator.pop()`

Although all three ways works but the preferred way of doing this is to use `SystemNavigator.pop()`. The method looks like this:

```
static Future<void> pop({bool animated}) async {
  await SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop', animated);
}
```

`exit(0)`is not a recommended way as it immediately terminates the process running in dart VM and looks a bit like your app is crashed.